# How do I find the rate constant when I only have product concentrations?

Tags: physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, kinetics, analytical-chemistry

I have done an experiment on the hydrolysis of aspirin, which is pseudo-first order. I need to find the rate constant, but I only have the final ($0.0278\mathrm{~M}$) and initial ($0\mathrm{~M}$) concentrations of the product (salicylic acid), the volume of the solution ($0.06\mathrm{~L}$), the change in time ($24$ hours), and the temperature ($25\mathrm{~^\circ C}$). Is there a way to find the rate constant of this reaction? My main problem is that I do not know the initial or the final reactant concentrations; I cannot simply subtract the concentration of product formed from initial reactant concentration to find the final reactant concentration, as I do not have either reactant concentration.

Comment: What's the relationship between the concentration of your product and the concentration of your reactant? I won't tell you any more. Figure it out yourself. It's important.

Comment: The reaction is Acetylsalicylic Acid + Water to Salicylic Acid + Acetic Acid

Comment: pseudo first order

Comment: You're not answering the question

Comment: what do you mean by relationship

Comment: An equation. Not a chemical equation. A mathematical equation relating the *concentration* of acetylsalicylic acid to the *concentration* of salicylic acid. The chemical equation will help you get there.

Comment: Try and figure it out yourself first. If you're really stuck look at this previous question http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32346/ I have to go off and won't be around to answer comments.

Comment: My main problem is that I do not know the initial or the final reactant concentrations; I cannot simply subtract the concentration of product formed from initial reactant concentration to find the final reactant concentration, as I do not have either reactant concentration.

Comment: Is this a real experiment in the lab, or is it just a question where you're given some kind of data?

Comment: This is a real experiment

Comment: Ok, sorry... Well, if you don't have data points along the way, it's going to be hard. *Normally*, in a kinetics experiment, you take samples from the reaction vessel at set intervals and measure the concentration of product at that point in time. This allows you to plot a graph of $\ln [\ce{X}]$ against $t$ and therefore find the rate constant.. *However*, if it is a real experiment, you should at least know the initial reactant concentration. I mean, you're the one who put a certain mass of the reactant in a certain amount of solvent.

Comment: Having two data points (initial and final) is not the end of the world, although it is not very ideal. You can still plot $\ln [\ce{X}]$ against $t$ (according to the integrated rate law) and you will have 2 data points - one at $t = 0$ and one at $t = 86400\mathrm{~s}$. Find the gradient and then find $k$. And when I say $\ce{X}$ I mean aspirin.

Comment: I used low dose Aspirin tablets with 81 mg of Acetylsalicylic Acid in them; however, due to error in the spectrophotometric evaluation of Salicylic Acid with Iron (III) Chloride, I achieved higher concentrations of Salicylic Acid than my initial reactant concentration, and so I was trying to determine a way to go backwards; to use my products to find the reactant concentrations.

Comment: The thing is I do not know the X; I know the Salicylic Acid concentration changes

Comment: Can I use the integrated rate law with products?

Comment: No... not when it's first-order and when one of your data points is 0. For the simple reason that you can't take the logarithm of 0.

Comment: Yeah that is why I am trying to find an alternative quantitative way to solve this.